# Null check in Stream filter

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of Student objects `studentList` as below.

```
Student1 = new Student("Student1", 10);
Student2 = new Student("Student2", 11);


Student {
 String name;
 int age;
}
```

I want to do a filter on the list and get the age of the particular Student.
I have tried the same as below using java 8 streams.

```
int age = studentList.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getName.equals("Student1"))
        .findFirst()
        .get()
        .getAge();
```

But when I pass a student name which is not in the list, say Student5, it will throw a null pointer exception. For that I have given the null check as below

```
Student s = studentList.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getName.equals("Student1"))
        .findFirst()
        .get();

if(s != null){
  age = s.getAge();
}
```

Instead of splitting this null check like this, is it possible to accomodate the null check in the stream().filter() code itself?

Comment: `get()` on an empty optional will throw a `NoSuchElementException`, not a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: That's not the complete case what you want when there is no student match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Stream#findFirst` returns `Optional<T>` which value you can remap if present:

```
int age = studentList.stream()
    .filter(x -> "Student1".equals(x.getName()))
    .findFirst()
    .map(Student::getAge)
    .orElse(0);
```

Comment: You can avoid boxing overhead by using `int age = studentList.stream() .filter(x -> "Student1".equals(x.getName())) .mapToInt(Student::getAge) .findFirst() .orElse(0);`

Answer (score 1):

First, reverse your test just in case that `getName` is returning a null.  The equals method should check for null before doing the comparison.  And then add a conditional in case there is not match for the student.

```
int age = studentList.stream()
           .filter(x -> "Student1".equals(x.getName()))
           .mapToInt(Student::getAge).findFirst().orElse(0);
```

Modified my answer based on an excellent suggestion by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) to reduce `boxing` overhead.